# Sublime Text 3 | Иероглифы в консоли

Tags: кодировка, sublime-text, sublime-text-3

Иероглифы в консоли. Как их убрать?
[image: Иероглифы в консоли]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: С большой вероятностью там написано что-то типа `"csc.exe" не является внешней или внутренней командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом`. Либо csc не установлен, либо путь к нему не добавлен в переменную окружения PATH.

Answer (score 1):

Поменяйте кодировку. File -> Reopen with Encoding.

Пробуйте UTF-8, Cyrillic(windows 1251), Cyrillic(xxx) и т.д.

Если это не поможет, то в коде вашей программы сделайте, чтобы вывод был в кодировке UTF-8.

Comment: Не помогло. Как сделать так?

Comment: Расскажите подробнее о вашей проблеме, мне надо понять что не так.

Comment: Запускаю код, хоть пустой хоть полный и появляются те иероглифы, которые в скриншоте вопроса. Билд использую скаченный через PackageContent CSharpSingleFileBuild

Comment: Можете скинуть вот сюда свой код, чтобы понять, и вопрос: Ваш скрипт написан на языке c# ?

Comment: Кажется понял, проблема может быть состоит в Windows, но это не точно, но возможно.

Comment: Да, на C#. Возможно проблема и в Windows

Comment: using System;

class Programm{
    public static void Main(){
        Console.WriteLine("sdfgh");
    }
}

Comment: Такая проблема только в Sublime Text, в Visual Studio такого нет

Comment: Попробуйте все настройки сделать по умолчанию (билд, и т.д)
Больше я не знаю причин.

Comment: Да, может и в Sublime Text проблема. Sublime юзает шрифт указанный в настройках cmd, так как default "font_face": ""